# AlertDialog Class Cast exception

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When i use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` then i get class cast option if i use

> setView(view)

method of AlertDialog . If i use `android.app.AlertDialog` then i have no crash but dialog is not in material style .

```
public class SearchFilterFragment extends DialogFragment {

boolean isAscending;
CheckBox checkbox;
View view;
SearchFilterInterface searchFilterInterface = null;
int which_one;
int array_id;


public interface SearchFilterInterface {

    void onSelect(int which, boolean asc);
}


public static SearchFilterFragment newInstance(@ArrayRes int array_id) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(GiantBomb.ARRAY,array_id);
    SearchFilterFragment fragment = new SearchFilterFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        searchFilterInterface = (SearchFilterInterface) getTargetFragment();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toaster.make(getContext(), "interface cast exception");
    }



}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    array_id = getArguments().getInt(GiantBomb.ARRAY);
    if (array_id==R.array.search_filter) {
        which_one = SharedPreference.getFromSharedPreferences(GiantBomb.WHICH, 4, getContext());
        isAscending = SharedPreference.getFromSharedPreferences(GiantBomb.ASCENDING, true, getContext());
    }else {
        which_one = SharedPreference.getFromSharedPreferences(GiantBomb.SORT_WHICH,1,getContext());
        isAscending = SharedPreference.getFromSharedPreferences(GiantBomb.SORT_ASCENDING,true,getContext());
    }
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_option_layout,null);

    checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    final int uncheck_color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.black_white);
    checkbox.setChecked(!isAscending);
    if (!checkbox.isChecked()) { checkbox.setTextColor(uncheck_color) ;}


    final AlertDialog dialog =  new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(),R.style.MyDialogTheme)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setTitle("Sort result")

            .setSingleChoiceItems(getResources().getStringArray(array_id), which_one, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    which_one = which;
                }
            })
           //crashes here if i use v7 AlertDialog class
            .setView(view)

            }).create();
            dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.primary));
                }
            });
            return dialog;
}
```

}

My custom view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="20dp"

>


<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Descending"
android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
android:drawableLeft="@android:color/transparent"
android:drawableStart="@android:color/transparent"
android:drawablePadding="20dp"
style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
 />


</FrameLayout>
```

MyDialogTheme

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!--item RadioButton or CheckBox color-->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black_white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
    <!--item text color-->
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <!--buttons color-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <!--title and message color-->
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/cardColor</item>

</style>
```

Stack trace

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:655)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:463)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:226)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
                                                                                   at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:361)
                                                                                   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:262)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:418)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2215)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is your `MyDialogTheme` an `AppCompat` theme? That is, is its `parent` an `AppCompat` theme?

Comment: yes it is AppCompat theme . Added the xml

Comment: Yeah, now that I'm looking at the source more closely, that wouldn't make sense as the cause. This really looks like a goof on their part, if I'm following the code correctly. When the `AlertDialog` has a `ListView`, it tries to correct the `weight` on the custom `View` container by casting its `LayoutParams` to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, but the container is in a `LinearLayoutCompat`, so you get that `ClassCastException`. Maybe it was never intended to allow a custom `View` and a list, and it's just luck that it works with the platform `AlertDialog`? Gotta say, I've never used it like that.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation . I am trying to fix this from past few days . I think i will post the bug on google forum .

Comment: Here's where it's choking: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AlertController.java#655. And you can see in [the layout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_material.xml#83) that it's in an `AlertDialogLayout`, which [`extends LinearLayoutCompat`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AlertDialogLayout.java#51).

Comment: Upon further thought, I'm thinking that you're just not supposed to use a custom `View` with the list provided by `AlertDialog`. You can see in that first link that, if there's a list, it tries to set the `weight` to 0, essentially hiding it. And if you're providing your own custom `View`, you can just include your own `ListView`/`RecyclerView` in that anyway, which I would bet is going to be the response if you file a bug report.

Comment: okay got it . I will just use my own listview . thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug in support-v7 library. For a workaround you can use a version <= 25.0.1

You can also follow the bug discussed in a related bug report:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231238